# Change image orientation in darktable from a lua script

Tags: darktable

I'm working on a lua script to import metadata from Shotwell to Darktable. Among other things I want to import the image orientation from the Shotwell database. But I can't seem to find an orientation attribute in Darktable's Lua API documentation. Can anyone tell me how to set/change an image's orientation through the Lua API?

Comment: According to this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/18420/680869 from Adam Dingle version 0.8 Shotwell can write the metadata in to the image.

Comment: I don't want Shotwell to modify the image; non-destructive editing is a main selling point of both Shotwell and Darktable and I want to take full advantage of that.

Answer (score 1):

It appears this isn't available through the Lua API. Currently there is an open [feature request](https://github.com/darktable-org/darktable/issues/9912) for image orientation to be exposed through the dt_lua_image_t data type.